# How to efficiently stream real time websocket data to web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, websocket, streaming

I've been trying to figure out the best way to stream real time data to a web app but suspect I may not be approaching it correctly. Basically, I have a next.js webapp and am streaming stock market data via websocket to a stock chart.

I need the chart to tick in real time but the data provider limits connections so I need to process the data on my own server and handle distribution to website users - I do have redistribution rights and am not violating terms of service.

Effectively I just need to figure out how to (1) pull data from websocket to server (2) expose same data via websocket from server (3) access data at site level.

Would this be a use case for Apache Kafka? I'm concerned with how to do this in a way that won't result in unscalable cloud hosting costs.

Sorry if I'm way off base here - not my wheelhouse and having no luck finding a starting point online. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What's the specific problem you're trying to solve?  Is it that you need to know how to use a pub/sub system like Redis?  That you need to know how to use Web Sockets?  How to represent the data efficiently?  Reduce bandwidth?  Reduce latency?  What sort of scale are you looking at anyway?

Comment: Something like Redis looks like what I need - I had been researching Apache Kafka. RE websocket, I have test version up streaming websocket data directly to live chart but bc of the # of allowed connections this won't work in production. Lost on how to consume that data elsewhere as an intermediate point and then send to the chart (via my own websocket?). Ultimately needs to be relatively low latency and efficient enough that I don't do something dumb and end up with a 10k cloud hosting bill. Not sure on scale but building a web app so hopefully many users!

Comment: How low latency is "relatively low latency"?  You could, for example, publish fresh data to a CDN every minute and reuse existing cheap HTTP-based CDNs.  Also, if you're only sending data one-way, consider server-sent events (SSE/EventSource).

Comment: Ideally it would need to publish data to the chart every second, maybe every 5 seconds would be doable if I could cache the preceding 5 seconds of data (10 data points per second) and then represent that on the chart with the same frequency but just under a 5 second delay

Comment: 5-second delay is doable via a regular HTTP-based CDN.  You'll have to decide then which tradeoffs are appropriate for your specific needs.  You can either go the easy/cheap route with this higher latency, or the more complex and expensive route of streaming the data from your own application.